# Using different .config files for separate threads (.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading, config

Is this possible to do?

I'm using this call to instantiate new thread:

```
this.RunningThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.Run));
```

Optionally, I'd like to pass a location of a different .config to it.  Is it possible, if so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean that the code that executes in the thread is not changed but still use a different .config? Or can you pass the path to the config file to the code executing on the thread?

Comment: I'd like to pass a different config file to the code that executes on the new thread only.  Main thread should use original .config that ships with the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a .config file is associated with an AppDomain, not a thread.  On the default CLR host, the primary appdomain is hard-baked to the app.exe.config file, you cannot change it.  New AppDomains can be configured with their own .config file through the AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile property.

Beware of the effort required to serialize data from one appdomain to another, this is something you only want to do if you are actually interested in isolating code.  Whatever the reason you want to do this, surely there's a better way than an AppDomain to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

just pass a delegate:

```
private void Run(string configPath)
{

}

...
Thread thread = new Thread(()=> this.Run("foo.config")) ;
thread.Start();
```

Comment: sorry, I didnt mean to pass it as a parameter, but I meant to have different thread consume automatically different .config file

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) method which you pass the path of the config file and returns a [`Configuration` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx).

I don't think there's any way to have [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) or [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) return different values on different threads, but you could keep a reference to the Configuration object returned by the [`OpenExeConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) method and use that within your code.